# How can I get a matrix with row and column labels that can also be aligned with a title?

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays

I'm seeking to replicate this image: [image: the table]

Is there a way to get this without using any external packages other than `tikz` (ideally just some combination of `\array` and `tabular`) or wild redefinitions? I prefer not using `blkarray` because it does bad things when attempting to make it spit out a bracket matrix.

So far I can do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} *{4}{c}}

&
0 &
1 &
2 &
3
\\[1ex]
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3  \\
1 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3  \\
2 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0  \\
3 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3  \\ 

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I like the answer initially given by @Werner, but it seems hard to modify for, say, my use case. Here's what I tried, which fails to align the brackets correctly:

```
\[
  P =
  \begin{array}{ *{5}{c} }
      \\[3\normalbaselineskip]
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\rowind{State}} \\
      & \colind{\$0} & \colind{\$1} & \colind{\$2} & \colind{\$3}  \\
    \rowind{0} &   0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
    \rowind{1} & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
    \rowind{2} \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{$%
      \hspace{.5\tabcolsep}\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
        \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut 
      \end{array}\right.
    $}} & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{$%
      \hspace{.5\tabcolsep}\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
        \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut 
      \end{array}\right]
    $}} \\
    \rowind{3} &  0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3  \\
  \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why not `tikz`? Using the matrix from `tikz` it should be possible i think.

Comment: @Ronny I'm fine with `tikz`! I'm more averse to the odd things like `kbordermatrix`.

Comment: Sorry I misread your sentence, however, the solution of Werner is quite nice.

Comment: Look in the site for `blkarray`

Comment: @egreg I'm averse to `blkarray` for the reason stated, along with it being a nonstandard import for my workflow.

Comment: @NathanielBechhofer [This picture (click here)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fNVC5.png) has been made with `blockarray`

Comment: @egreg I'm impressed, but unconvinced that's easy to generalize to different sizes.

Comment: @Ronny, I love that solution, but I would like more clarification on how to make sure the brackets always work.

Comment: @NathanielBechhofer You start your question with "I'm seeking to replicate this image". You're not asking how to generalize.

Comment: @egreg I should've added an 'e.g.' but my title should be clear enough…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course! I've made some definitions to avoid repetition of content which also allows for tweaking it if you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\indsize}{\scriptsize}
\newcommand{\colind}[2]{\displaystyle\smash{\mathop{#1}^{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{\indsize #2}}}}
\newcommand{\rowind}[1]{\mbox{\indsize #1}}

\begin{document}

\[
  P =
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \rowind{0} \\ \rowind{1} \\ \rowind{2} \\ \rowind{3} \\ \rowind{4}
  \end{array}
  \mathop{\left[
  \begin{array}{ *{5}{c} }
     \colind{1}{\$0}  &  \colind{0}{\$1}  &  \colind{0}{\$2}  & \colind{0}{\$3} & \colind{0}{\$4} \\
    1-p &  0  &  p  & 0 & 0 \\
     0  & 1-p &  0  & p & 0 \\
     0  &  0  & 1-p & 0 & p \\
     0  &  0  &  0  & 0 & 1
  \end{array}
  \right]}^{
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \rowind{State} \\ \mathstrut
  \end{array}
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to generalize very well when I try to change the dimensions.

Comment: @NathanielBechhofer: You'll have to explain...

Comment: I'm not sure how I would change the dimension if I wanted, say, a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: I'm trying it for my case in the MWE and failing to get the brackets correct.

Comment: The negative vertical skip at the start ensures the matrix will overlap previous contents.

Comment: @egreg Changing that doesn't fix the problem…

Comment: @NathanielBechhofer: See the updated suggestion.

Comment: @Werner I do have one question though…if I change \indsize to be \normalsize and do a four by four, the top labels don't align with each other. Any idea why?

Comment: See http://i.imgur.com/KnXtmjY.png

Comment: @NathanielBechhofer: Your first entry should be `\colind{0\vphantom{/}}{0}`.

Comment: @Werner you are correct of course